# Relation does not exist in Django

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, backend

The backend of the app I'm working at is created with Django. When I updated a project from GitHub, I started to get such an error when I try to run the project via docker-compose.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    perfect_cv_local_django |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    perfect_cv_local_django |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    perfect_cv_local_django | psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "..." does not exist
    perfect_cv_local_django | LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "..."
```

I've already tried to migrate the DB, but I keep getting the same mistake.
P.S I'm working on frontend part of this app so I'm not really familiar with backend.

Comment: there is no such table in your database. try makemigrations then migrate again, and if you can't provide more info, then we can't really help you with this